# SQL Error - null auto increment

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a mySQL tutorial to learn how to write sql statements. I keep getting this:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''add_delete_record' ( 'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'content' text' at line 1
```

This is the sql I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'add_delete_record' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'content' text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is the exact code the tutorial gave, so I am not sure if the tutorial is just older than my version of mysql(v5.5) or if I have something tiny wrong that I am missing.

Comment: Use [backticks](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b4456) NOT single quotes

Comment: @StuartLC I have written everything I am running right there in the question.

Comment: @StuartLC I wrote that before you edited your comment, ok I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using backticks(`) instead of single quotes (').

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_delete_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dab84)

Comment: Ya that worked. Was there a change to the syntax in newer versions of mysql?

Comment: No there was not a change.  Single quotes have never been allowed to be used that way you're using them.  You can play around with earlier versions of MySql on the SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all single quotes from everywhere the query will run fine.